# How modern messengers encryption keys can't be hacked

Tags: algorithm-design, protocol-design, key-exchange, secret-sharing, related-keys

I dont know is this question more like reverse-engineering or cryptographic.
Why governments are hunting for encryptions keys? Aren't they delievering by the network the same as the encypted messages? What doing it end-to-end encrypted?

Answer (score 2):

> Aren't they delievering by the network the same as the encypted messages?

No. At least not in the plain.

> What doing it end-to-end encrypted?

Try to search for the *key agreement* protocol (e. g. [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) ) and *asymmetric encryption* (e.g. [RSA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) ).

The "asymmetric" encryption allows sending encrypted and signed messages without sharing the private (secret) key.

Very simplistically explained - each actor creates a key pair (with a public and private part) and the actors will exchange their public key. That allows both actors to securely create a shared secret even on an unsecure channel

Comment: Absolutely not clear for me. Diffie-Hellman is a method of symmetric encryption (which means that every side should have an decryption key). So transefring it over network/having it built inside a programm is making this not secure at all. About asymmetric - even wikipedia says that its middle man weak - keys can be stolen

Comment: @chillitshvh  DH is an **asymmetric key agreement** protocol, both parties have different keys and they can compute a common one. Indeed the DH itself is not enough (that's why RSA is needed as well), and more. I just gave you hints of basic technologies used today for encrypted traffic. From the question it is not clear what protocols do you have in mind, you may try search how [TLS](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246) works, if you search for a messaging protocol, you may have a look at [Signal protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_Protocol) (more complex, but a complete example)